# Is first order logic with an equivalence relation and existence of infinitely many objects, complete?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Lets work in *First order logic without equality* extended with a primitive binary relation symbol $\rightleftharpoons$, with the following axioms:

**Reflexive:** $\forall x: x\rightleftharpoons x$

**Symmetric:** $\forall x,y: x\rightleftharpoons y \to y\rightleftharpoons x$

**Transitive:** $\forall x,y,z: x\rightleftharpoons y \land y\rightleftharpoons z \to x\rightleftharpoons z$

**Existence:** $\text{For }n=1,2,3,...\\ \forall x_1,..,x_n \exists y \ (y \not \rightleftharpoons x_1 \land...\land y \not \rightleftharpoons x_n)$

Is this theory *complete*?

Comment: Do you allow empty models?

Comment: No, first order logic is supposed to forbid that, isn't it?

Comment: Well traditionally it does but this is a rather silly historical relic that is not universally followed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because it is $\aleph_0$-categorical and has no finite models.

Also, in standard first-order logic with equality, your first three axioms are tautologies (they can be proved from no hypotheses), so they don't need to be assumed.

---

After discussion in the comments, it seems you're actually asking about first-order logic *without* equality. So a model of your theory looks like a set $M$ equipped with an equivalence relation $=$ with infinitely many classes. Any two such models are elementarily equivalent (in first-order logic without equality), so your theory is indeed complete.

Comment: How they can be proved from no hypothesis. The only axioms that I know are the logical axioms, but those three axioms are not among them?

Comment: @Zuhair: "First-order logic with equality" does not just mean first-order logic with $=$ as a relation symbol.  It means a variant of first-order logic where $=$ is a logical symbol and certain axioms regarding this symbol are built into the logic.

Comment: Possibly you are referring to the substitution axiom. I'm not assuming it here!

Comment: This depends on your proof system. But every complete proof system for first-order logic includes rules for equality, which typically include reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity.

Comment: @EricWofsey, what I know is the substitution axiom and the reflexive axiom, but I'm not assuming the former scheme here

Comment: You can also think about it this way: reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity are true in every model of the empty theory, so they must be provable from the empty theory, by the completeness theorem. If this doesn't hold, your proof system is deficient (it doesn't satisfy completeness).

Comment: If you want to continue this discussion, please provide a reference for your definition (proof system and semantics) for "first-order logic with equality".

Comment: @AlexKruckman, what I meant above by "first order logic with equality" is just adding equality to first order logic without any further axioms. The only additional axioms are the ones I've mentioned. This is the theory I'm asking about. The only inference rule is modus Ponens

Comment: @Zuhair Please do not call this "first-order logic with equality" - this term has a standard meaning, which is different from the way you're using it. Your system would be called "first-order logic *without* equality in the language consisting of a binary relation symbol $=$" (though in this case I would also strongly recommend using a different symbol, since $=$ is essentially always interpreted as true equality).

Comment: @AlexKruckman, Ok I've edited the symbols to avoid the confusion. Thanks